# How to downgrade the Next js version from ^12.2.2 to 12.2.2?

Tags: npm, next.js

i am working on next js project and the version used is 12.2.2. mistakenly i upgraded to ^12.2.2 and now i get this warning in my terminal "You have defined experimental feature (outputStandalone) in next.config.js that does not exist in this version of Next.js". How can i work again on the previous version?

Answer (score 9):

If it's just the package version and nothing else changed when you ran an npm upgrade, try:

1. delete the node_modules folder
2. edit `package.json` to set the version you want (12.2.2)
3. run `npm install` again

That should remove the old version and the install the specific one you want.

Comment: Isn't it more efficient to just do `npm uninstall next`?